# Laravel - Filtering and Grouping Collections with different Types

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, collections, eloquent

I have a collections of two different types.

```
Collection {#277 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    "" => Collection {#271 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => {#265 ▼
          +"id": 3
          +"name": "Product 3"
          +"cover_image": ""
        }
        1 => {#273 ▼
          +"id": 9
          +"name": "Product 9"
          +"cover_image": ""
        }
      ]
    }
    1 => Collection {#272 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => SuperProducts {#282 ▼
          +timestamps: true
          #table: "super_products"
          #fillable: array:6 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:9 [▶]
          #original: array:9 [▶]
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #events: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The first collection was an arrays transformed to collections, without using Eloquent. Second is SuperProduct Collection. Both collections combined together using merge. Is there a way I can groupBy these two different collections with type? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load a sub item from your SuperProducts ?
If that's the case you should load your main collection of SuperProducts with your sub-items using eloquent relationship like this:

```
App\SuperProducts::with('name_of_your_relation') [..]
```

If it's not the case your should append result to your collection like this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Hope it's help

Comment: Basically its two different collections, one converted from array another from model. So I'd like to serialize them but not sure how

Comment: Is the first collection, the array, dynamically generated or he is static ?